# When I tryto install npm googleapis it gives me this error and doesn't save the package-lock.json file what should I do?

Tags: json, npm, google-apis-explorer

> npm install googleapis@39 --save
>   npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Youssef\package.json'
>   npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Youssef\package.json'
>   npm WARN Youssef No description
>   npm WARN Youssef No repository field.
>   npm WARN Youssef No README data
>   npm WARN Youssef No license field.

****+ googleapis@39.2.0
updated 1 package and audited 447 packages in 7.422s
found 22 high severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details****

Comment: Are you doing this in an npm setup project, i.e. you've run `npm init` first.

Comment: I did use npm init first and then tried to reinstall it it gave me the same problem then I tried to install npm install googleapis and this worked then I tried the googleapis@40 version and this worked, but I don't know the problem with this specific version the @39 one.